# Can't access office365 Calendar API using Azure trial account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I want to get an access to Calendar rest API. I've created azure multi-tenant app, and configured it.

I'm trying to get an access token to resource "https://outlook.office365.com/", but I get an error

'AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://outlook.office365.com/' is disabled.'

Note: I couldn't find "Office 365 Exchange Online" inside "Permissions to other applications" section inside azure account.

Your help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see Exchange in your Azure account unless you have an Office 365 subscription that includes Exchange. It sounds like you're registering in https://manage.windowsazure.com? You might want to try registering your app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and using the v2 Azure auth flow. Big benefit is you can register apps with just a Microsoft account (like outlook.com, etc) See https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted for walkthroughs.